# Why is GLUT loading the image tilted, and shifted upsidedown over window like a circular buffer?

Tags: c++, opencv, opengl

I put together a glut initializer and image view using glut functions and opencv's IplImage data structure, but for some unfortunate reason the outcome isn't as straightforward.

This is the real image 
[image]

This is the actual outcome
[image]

First I run the following function:

```
void initGlutTools(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* Get Image */
    IplImage *image = cvLoadImage(imagePath.c_str(), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    if(image == NULL) cout << "Cannot open image " << endl;
    cout << "width: " << image->width << "height: " << image->height << endl;
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(image->width, image->height);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow("Iancovici's 2D Particle Filter");

    gluOrtho2D(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    glEnable( GL_POINT_SMOOTH );
    glEnable( GL_BLEND );
    glBlendFunc( GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA );
    glPointSize( 1.0 );

    glClearColor ( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
    glShadeModel( GL_SMOOTH );
    glDisable( GL_LIGHTING );
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, 0);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
    glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, image->width, image->height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image->imageData);
    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );

    glutDisplayFunc(&gl_display);
    glutIdleFunc(&gl_idle);

}
```

The, gl_display function is as follows

```
void gl_display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Draw background.
    glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
    glColor3f(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
    glVertex2f(0, 1);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
    glVertex2f(0, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
    glVertex2f(1, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
    glVertex2f(1, 1);
    glEnd();

    // Draw objects.
    glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glPointSize(1.0);

    // Draw poses
    glPointSize(5.0f);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2f(real_pose.x / MAP_WIDTH, real_pose.y / MAP_HEIGHT);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    glVertex2f(best_pose.x / MAP_WIDTH, best_pose.y / MAP_HEIGHT);
    glEnd();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

The gl_idle function is simply

```
void gl_idle(void)
{    
    glutPostRedisplay();
    sleep(0.05);
}
```

Lastly, on a concurrent thread I run glutMainLoop

But I'm not exactly sure what could cause this to be morphed. I thought it might have something to do with the glBegin(GL_QUADS) to glEnd where you define the vertex and texture coordinates, but no go here.

Comment: Just from the visual experience, my bet is that the image is RGBA, and you're using it as RGB.

Comment: And (0,0) is bottom left for glut, and top left for OpenCV.

Comment: @RetoKoradi: no, this tilt indicates the stride is different from `width * bytes_per_pixels`. It could be an error inside `cvLoadImage`. What is in `imagePath`? (Probably a simple CString because of the `.c_str()` suffix, but then again you never know.) Is the image correct when you open it with a viewing tool? (Probably "yes"...) What are its dimensions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenCV's [IlpImage](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/old_basic_structures.html#iplimage) does not store the images as a tightly packed array, as your GL code currently suggests. Instead, each line might be aligned. The relevant field describing this is `widthStep`, which defines the byte offset between two consecutive rows. Unfortunately, this does not directly map to the GL, which accepts an `GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGHT` only in *pixels*. For the extra alignment, you have to break this manually into an `GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH` and an `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT`.

If your input format is RGB with 1 byte per channel, this should work:

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, image->widthStep/3);
int align=1;
for (int s=image->widthStep; (align<8) && !(s&1); s>>=1)
    align<<=1;
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, align);
```

This of course assumes the image rows are aligned at 1,2,4 or 8 byte boundaries, otherwise you can't feed the data directly into the GL anyway.